# I keep getting Cannot find symbol method compareTo ERROR

Tags: java, object, interface, comparable, compareto

I want my program to compare two objects but I keep getting an error message, "Cannot find symbol method compareTo(Product)". But I've already checked and I did define the compareTo method in the Tool class as you can see below.

```
public class InventoryDemo
{
   public static List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

    products.add(new Car("Jaguar", 1000000.00));
    products.add(new Car("Neon", 17000.00));
    products.add(new Tool("JigSaw", 149.18));
    products.add(new Car("Jaguar", 110000.00));
    products.add(new Car("Neon", 17500.00));
    products.add(new Car("Neon", 17875.32));
    products.add(new Truck("RAM",  35700.00));
    products.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 200.00));
    products.add(new Tool("CircularSaw", 150.00));


    InventoryDemo.takeInventory("CircularSaw");
    if(products.get(7).compareTo(products.get(8)) == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The price of Saw1 and the price of Saw2 are the same.");

    }
    else if(products.get(7).compareTo(products.get(8)) == 1)
    {
       System.out.println("Saw1 is more expensive tham Saw2.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Saw2 is more expensive tham Saw1.");
    }


}

public class Tool implements Product, Comparable<Tool>
{

private String name;
private double cost;

public Tool(String name, double cost)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public double getCost()
{
    return cost;
}
public int compareTo(Tool t)
{
    if(cost > t.cost)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(cost == t.cost)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your product?

Comment: you need to check in compareTo method this.cost>t.cost

Answer (score 0):

That might be because you are holding the instance in a interface holder and interface is not having any info about it.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is
whenever you do `products.get(anything)` it returns a Product class object(although underlying it might be a Tool object) and when you call compareTo method on this.

Compiler looks for `compareTo` method in Product class and not in Tool class.

this happens because in java you can only call a method which is defined in same class or super class.
for Example have a look at this

```
Class A{
    public void read(){
        ...
    }
}
Class B extends A{
    public void write(){
        ...
    }
}
Class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A aObj=new B(); //works fine
        aObj.write(); //this is compilation error becaue compiler cannot find write method in Class A definition
    }
}
```

So for your programme to work fine you need to implement Comparable interface in Product

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You implemented `compareTo(Tool t)` method in class `Tool`. In `InventoryDemo`, the compareTo() is invoked by type `Product`. Do you have the compareTo() implemented in `Product` interface?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Tool`'s compareTo method can compare 2 Tools. However, your ArrayList contains elements of `Product` type, an interface with multiple implementations. For example, you have no logic that compares a Tool to a Car.

You could change your `Product` interface to extend `Comparable<Product>`. Then all the classes that implement it will be forced to implement `compareTo(Product)`, and you'll be able to call `compareTo` on any two elments of your `products` List.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

`products.get(7).compareTo(products.get(8))` its same as (actually Compiler generate equivalent bytecode.)

```
Product product = (Product)products.get(7); // This how Generics work at run time.
product.compareTo(products.get(8)) //Error Product class doesn't have `compareTo`
```

to get around this problem, add a `compareTo` method to `Product` class and let the subclasses implement it.